# Trying to remove a hover overlay in Squarespace with jQuery or CSS

Tags: jquery, css, squarespace

When I hover over the navigation bar, the fullscreen pictures have a light or dark overlay that slightly obscures the picture. Not a big deal but my client wants it gone and it's not a regular style editor option in Squarespace.

The dev tools give me the class names of the things I need to edit, but the CSS and jQuery I'm writing doesn't appear to be doing anything. This is one of the options I tried in the code injection window.

What am I doing wrong?

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<script>
  $(“#canvas”).removeClass(“color-weight-light”);
  $(“#canvas”).removeClass(“color-weight-dark”);
</script>
```

I have also tried adding a

```
.show-overlay{ display: none; }
```

to the CSS page but that has no effect either.

Comment: Do you get a JS error?

Comment: there are some but they were there before and when I delete the jQuery stuff they're still there so I guess they're unrelated